# Why the max value of cornerRadius is not half of the rectangle? Drawing roundedRect with UIBezierPath in swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics, quartz-2d

as the document says the cornerRadius can not larger than half width, but in my code it only 1/3 of the width the round rect become a circle, can't know why? need help

document:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624356-init

> cornerRadius:
> The radius of each corner oval. A value of 0 results in a rectangle without rounded corners. Values larger than half the rectangle’s width or height are clamped appropriately to half the width or height.

```
var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 94, height: 94), cornerRadius: 31)
path.stroke()

path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 94, height: 94), cornerRadius: 30.5)
path.stroke()
                
path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 400, width: 94, height: 94), cornerRadius: 31.5)
path.stroke()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of a type casting error.

Try this.

```
let xCor: CGFloat = 50.0
let width: CGFloat = 94.0
let height: CGFloat = 94.0

let cornerRadius: CGFloat = width / 3.0

var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: xCor, y: 200.0, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
path.stroke()

path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: xCor, y: 300.0, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
path.stroke()
                
path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: xCor, y: 400.0, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
path.stroke()
```

PS: didnt check by running this code let me know if there is any problem here.